# Show that $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 (p^2)$ has $0, 1, 2 \text{ or } p$ solutions

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

$f(x):=ax^2+bx+c$, $p$ an odd prime

I know that $f(x) \equiv 0 (p)$ can have $0, 1 \text{ or } 2$ solutions depending on the value of $b^2 - 4ac$. So using this, I started developing this and couldn't find a case where $f(x) \equiv 0 (p^2)$ might have just one solution. I've found the following:

If $f(x) \equiv 0 (p)$ has $0$ solutions, $f(x) \equiv 0 (p^2)$ will have no solutions (if there is one, then it's also a solution for the first one)

If $f(x) \equiv 0 (p)$ has 1 solution, means $b^2-4ac\equiv 0(p)$ and from a theorem I've seen, if $u$ is a solution for $f(x) \equiv 0 (p)$ then $2au+b\equiv 0 (p)$. So what I did was see what happens with $f(u+tp)$ mod $p$. After some calculations, I've reached that $f(u+tp)\equiv p(q+pq't)(p^2)$ where $pq=f(u)$ and $pq' = 2au+b$, so $f(u+tp)\equiv 0 (p^2) \iff q \equiv0(p)$, so it has either $0$ solutions or $p$ solutions

If $f(x) \equiv 0 (p)$ has 2 solutions, then these are $u, -u$ for some $u$, since $p$ is odd these are not the same number. So, calculating again $f(u+tp)$, I reach that the condition is that either $q+(2au+b)t \equiv 0(p)$ or $q+(-2au+b)t \equiv 0(p)$, and since neither of $2au+b$ and $-2au+b$ are $0$ because these are the solutions of $x^2 \equiv b^2-4ac \not\equiv 0(p)$, then for each one exists one t such that these hold, so there are two different solutions.

Is the book wrong? Or am I missing something? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x \equiv 0 (p^2)$ is a simple example of such an equation with precisely 1 root modulo $p^2$.

Comment: In this case $a \equiv 0 (p)$. Is this the only case it might happen?

Comment: It was the obvious thing to do since your proof assumed a quadratic. If your proof is correct (and we can both check it now) then it is the only possibility.

Comment: I agree with your argument - having 1 root forces $a$ to be 0 mod $p$.